# How to refresh the contents of non-streaming dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v to streaming in my PoC.

I have a scenario where I need to load the previous data from hdfs/cassandra table and compare the streaming contents against which, I.e. joining non-streaming dataframe and streaming dataframe.

If contents found I need to update the data in hdfs/cassandra table , else add a new row to the table/hdfs.

Next time same streaming (above added) contents come , i need to update the record again ...

So my problem is , when I loaded dataframe from hdfs/cassandra table initially that wont contain recently added data.

So **how to refresh the loaded  dataframe from hdfs/cassandra table  every time new batch of stream processed ? What is the practice followed in general to handle this kind of scenario?**

Thank you.

Comment: In cassandra write will work as upsert

Comment: I read it and that's why said cassandra... Cassandra will itself take care of Update/Insert based on row key

Comment: and with cassandra if you want to hit table better approach will be joinWithCassandra... I am not sure how hbase works in similar scenario

Comment: yes... whenever data comes in streaming context you need to update or insert based on whether record is available in table or not

Comment: that is what I said if backend is cassandra it will do upsert (cassandra internally will take care of insert/update)... if you are not happy with it then use joinWithCassandra in every batch (this is of no use)

Comment: Are you using Cassandra or DSE with DSE Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I can say only about Cassandra, not about HDFS.

Basically, in Cassandra there is no difference between insert and update - you can issue `UPDATE` command even if the record with corresponding primary key doesn't exist, or you can execute `INSERT` for row that already exists - in both cases, the data will be set to given values.

Talking about refreshing the data from Cassandra - for such cases, Spark Cassandra Connector provides [2 functions](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable): `joinWithCassandra` & `leftJoinWithCassandra` - they both work on RDDs only. First function takes RDD & returns a new Pair RDD consisting of the original data on left, and data from Cassandra on the right - if no row corresponds the original data, it won't be included into result. The second function is similar, but leaves original data in the RDD even if there is no row in the Cassandra - in this case, the right part will be null.  Both functions are usually used to perform effective lookup of data, for example, to enrich the data coming from stream with additional information.

In DSE Analytics, there is also support for join of DataFrame against Cassandra, so called "[DSE Direct Join](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/)" - it's much more effective than Spark join to dataframe that holds all data from Cassandra, as it will pull only necessary records from database, without reading all data.